# TikZ matrix library compile error "Missing } inserted"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am only trying with a very naive example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then when I compile, it gives off a long list of errors, starting with a few couples of these:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.7 \end{tikzpicture}
                     
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Then the following error repeat for many times

```
! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.7 \end{tikzpicture}
                     
I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 
                    
l.7 \end{tikzpicture}
                     
I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
or \cr or \span just now. If something like a right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

This ONLY happens when I use the `\matrix` command.  Tikz compiles without any problem on any other commands.
Does anyone know why this is happening?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row of the matrix needs to be terminated with `\\` - even if you only have a single row.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] {a\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```